# Could not install from "../shared" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy my firebase functions but I'm encountering the error. I have a local dependency which I pack with my functions and it works fine on my local environment but I can't deploy it on cloud. It was working fine months ago but now I can't find the issue. Can someone please help me out on this?
I have tried all my luck by deleting node_modules from both shared and function folder and tried reinstalling but deployment still causes the issue.

NodeJS version 12.13.0
NPM 6
firebase-tool 7.16.1

Here is my package.json file for functions

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "pack:loanshub-shared": "npm pack file:../shared",
    "update-models": "npm run pack:loanshub-shared && npm install loanshub-shared -force",
    "build": "tsc && npm run pack:loanshub-shared",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "tslint-check": "tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json",
    "deploy-backend": "firebase deploy --only functions,firestore:rules,storage:rules,database:rules && firebase use preview",
    "deploy:preview": "firebase use preview && npm run deploy-backend",
    "deploy:production": "firebase use production && npm run deploy-backend",
    "emulate": "firebase use preview && npm run get-config && firebase functions:shell && firebase emulators:exec \"./tests/test.sh\"",
    "get-config": "firebase use preview && firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/**.spec.ts"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.6",
    "firebase": "^7.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "3.14.1",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "loanshub-shared": "file:loanshub-shared-1.0.0.tgz",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.11",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.14",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.46",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.17",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to migrate your functions to version 3, which might have better compatibility and improvement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).